# 2D positions: Find which positions are on a vector and calculate

Tags: python, 2d

I have a two dimensional grid, with a float value for each of positions:

```
p = [
  [0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ],
  [0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,1.0,0  ],
  [0  ,0.5,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ],
  [0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ],
  [0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ],
  [0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,0  ],
]
```

I would like to know what are poitions under a vector. For example, what are positions under vector `(p[5][0], p[0][2])` (A->C) and vector `(p[5][0], p[0][5])` (A->B):

[image: grid without coloration]

Result should be colored cases:

[image: grid with coloration]

So, for:

- `(p[5][0], p[0][2])` (A->C) => `(p[5][0], p[4][0], p[4][3], p[3][3], p[2][3], p[1][3], p[1][3], p[0][3])` and final values `(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0)`
- `(p[5][0], p[0][5])` (A->B) => `(p[5][0], p[4][1], p[3][2], p[2][3], p[1][4], p[0][5])` and final values `(0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0)`

How to compute that ?

Comment: Looks like you are looking for the [*Bresenham line algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: More like [reinventing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reinvent) it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's totally that :) Thank's. You can post an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As say `Willem Van Onsem` i was searching a `Bresenham line algorithm`.